# Embedded database for a simple portable application

Tags: sqlite, sql-server-ce, portability, embedded-database

I am going to develop small WPF application. Target platform is .NET 3.5. The main goal is to make it portable (move to any folder and it works out of the box). It should run on Windows 7 machine without any additional installations. However I need a database into it (not need ORM support, just simple storage). Could you please suggest database that would be better for this purpose? I think about SQL CE 4.0 but I am not sure whether it requires additional installations like C++ libs or not. Including DLLs is OK.

Comment: You can just include files with SQL CE 4.0, as described on my blog

Comment: Will it work on .NET 3.5? I heard that SQL CE 4.0 does not support this platform.

Comment: Then you heard wrong... Yes, it will Work with .NET 3.5 SP1 just fine.

Comment: Okay thank you. It's really great that I can use it.